# Combining different constructions with the same coordinator, is it possible?

Tags: grammaticality

I hope you're having a good time.

-"Delivery of the sale item sold shall consist of the placement of such item in the possession of the purchaser or that he can take possession of and enjoy them without hindrance as long as the seller so notifies the purchaser. The delivery shall be in manner aligned with the nature of the sale item."

*This is taken from the feedback on my translation of a legal document*

the subordinate clause "***that he can take possession of and enjoy them without hindrance,"*** isn't it odd or even ungrammatical to use a construction that is different from the one used before the coordinator? you cannot say, for example, **I love playing basketball** and *to watch TV.*

I can't remember exactly what that rule was :D.

thanks for all the help! I truly appreciate it.

Comment: Your first question (asking which paragraph is more grammatical) is off-topic because it does not identify any particular issue. If you try to salvage this question, please stick to this site's guidelines. (For example, you should cite the source of quoted text.)

Comment: how is it now??

Comment: Yes, the post is better now, thanks. Who wrote that paragraph? Was it a native speaker? It doesn't seem to be an example of good English.

Comment: It's not a native speaker who wrote it. I am not a native speaker either. That's why I wanted to ask about which paragraph is more grammatical, but I had to edit the post.

Comment: There are a number of issues. Does sale here mean something on sale at a lower price or not? If not, it is not clear.  Also, we don't place sold widgets in the possession of someone. Also, enjoy is not commonly used in texts like this. Enjoy is used mostly in the expression quiet enjoyment of a property like a house or apartment.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct; in general, we try to keep conjuncts (the components of a series that are usually connected with "and", "or", or commas) as similar as possible. In this case, a subordinate clause ("that he can take possession of and enjoy them without hindrance") seems to be the second conjunct of a series, but there is no earlier subordinate clause that could serve as the first conjunct.

One possible fix would be to change "or" to "so". In that case, we would get an adverbial clause:

> . . . shall consist of the placement of such item in the possession of the purchaser so that he can take possession . . .

Comment: I can't thank you enough!